# Proper way of passing classes into child components in MUI?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I was using material-UI, but then I decided to migrate to MUI. Which I found was complicated change because.

**Material UI format**

```
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core";

export const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
      display: 'flex',
    //   alignItems: 'center',
      width: '100%',
      position: 'relative',
      // backgroundColor: '#C2C2C2',
    //   marginTop: '700px',
      height: theme.spacing(65)
      // color: 'white',
    //   justifyContent: 'space-between'
    },
  }));
```

**TO**

**MUI Format**

```
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';

export const useStyles = () => ({
  Root: styled('div')(({theme}) => ({
    height: theme.spacing(10),
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    width: '100%',
    position: 'relative',
    color: 'white',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    [theme.breakpoints.down('xs')]: {
      // justifyContent: 'center'
      padding: '0 10px 0 10px'
    }
  })),
  Logo: styled('div')(({theme}) => ({
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    gap: '1em',
    letterSpacing: '0.5em',
    "& h4": {
      fontSize: '1.8em'
    },
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
      marginLeft: '2em',
    }
  })),
})
```

Which is fine, but the problem is that earlier, I had some components like this.

`<AnimeLogoWhite className={classes.logoIcon} />`

Now, this component simply took the class `logoIcon` and applied it.

```
logoIcon: {
         height: theme.spacing(6),
         position: 'relative',
         // iphone SE custom breakpoint
         [theme.breakpoints.down(325)]: {
           height: theme.spacing(5)
         }
     },
```

**AnimeLogoWhite.tsx**

```
import { FC } from 'react';
import whiteLogo from '../../../public/arkAnimeLogoWhite.svg';

interface Props {
    className: string
}

export const AnimeLogoWhite: FC<Props> = ({className}) => {
    return(
        <img className={className} src={whiteLogo.src} alt='' />
    )
}
```

I can't do this further with MUI.

Can anyone help me on how to achieve something similar?